# override ResourceOwner class for Wordpress

Tags: php, symfony, service, oauth-2.0, hwioauthbundle

I went to override [WordpressResourceOwner](https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/blob/master/OAuth/ResourceOwner/WordpressResourceOwner.php) into `HWIOAuthBundle` as it didn`t return user information response

I notice that every ResourceOwner work as Service and declared into [oauth.xml](https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/oauth.xml)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had override registration twig into `HWIOAuthBundle` and create new bundle inherit from `HWIOAuthBundle` like [answer of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20998778/how-i-can-override-hwioauthbundle-twig-file) but I can`t work the same with [WordpressResourceOwner](https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/blob/master/OAuth/ResourceOwner/WordpressResourceOwner.php)

after searching I had found we can override class of WordpressResourceOwner Service

**Steps**:

1) create new ResourceOwner

EX:

```
namespace project\OAuthBundle\OAuth\ResourceOwner;

use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\OAuth\ResourceOwner\GenericOAuth2ResourceOwner;
use HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\OAuthToken;

/**
 * Override WordpressResourceOwner class into HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\OAuth\ResourceOwner\WordpressResourceOwner 
 *
 * @author ahmedhamdy
 * 
 */
class WordpressResourceOwner extends GenericOAuth2ResourceOwner
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    protected $paths = array(
        'identifier'     => 'ID',
        'nickname'       => 'username',
        'realname'       => 'display_name',
        'email'          => 'email',
        'profilepicture' => 'avatar_URL',
    );

  /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    protected function doGetUserInformationRequest($url, array $parameters = array())
    {
        $apiAccessToken = $parameters['apiAccessToken'];
        $headers = array(
            0 => 'authorization: Bearer '.$apiAccessToken,
        );
        return $this->httpRequest($url,null,$headers);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function getUserInformation(array $accessToken, array $extraParameters = array())
    {
        $url = $this->normalizeUrl($this->options['infos_url'], array(
            'access_token' => $accessToken['access_token']
        ));

        $parameters = array(
            'apiAccessToken' => $accessToken['access_token'],
        );

        $content = $this->doGetUserInformationRequest($url,$parameters)->getContent();
        $response = $this->getUserResponse();
        $response->setResponse($content);
        $response->setResourceOwner($this);
        $response->setOAuthToken(new OAuthToken($accessToken));

        return $response;
    }


    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    protected function configureOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        parent::configureOptions($resolver);

        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'authorization_url' => 'https://public-api.wordpress.com/oauth2/authorize',
            'access_token_url'  => 'https://public-api.wordpress.com/oauth2/token',
            'infos_url'         => 'https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1/me',
        ));
    }
}
```

2) create CompilerPass class to override service class like  [Symfony2 documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/override.html#services-configuration)

EX:

```
namespace project\OAuthBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;

/**
 * OverrideWordpressResourceOwner
 *
 * @author ahmedhamdy
 */

class OverrideWordpressResourceOwner  implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $definition = $container->getDefinition("hwi_oauth.abstract_resource_owner.wordpress");
        $definition->setClass('ProfileTree\OAuthBundle\OAuth\ResourceOwner\WordpressResourceOwner');
    }
}
```

3) we must override `build` method into `Bundle class` like  [Symfony2 documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/compiler_passes.html)

EX:

```
namespace Project\OAuthBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use ProfileTree\OAuthBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler\OverrideWordpressResourceOwner;

class ProfileTreeOAuthBundle extends Bundle
{

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'HWIOAuthBundle';
    }

    public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        parent::build($container);

        $container->addCompilerPass(new OverrideWordpressResourceOwner());
    }
}
```

4) last step calling `compile` method for  [ContainerBuilder](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php)  into Bundle Extension like  [Symfony2 documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/compilation.html)

EX:

```
namespace Project\OAuthBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\Extension;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader;

/**
 * This is the class that loads and manages your bundle configuration
 *
 * To learn more see {@link http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html}
 */
class ProfileTreeOAuthExtension extends Extension
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

        $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('services.yml');

        $container->compile();

    }
}
```